# Right Join in Doctrine2 for Symfony2

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following working MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM bogenantworten a
    RIGHT JOIN
        bogenfragen f ON f.id = a.bogenfragen_id
        AND a.personen_id = 3,
    BogenTyp t, 
    BogenFragenGruppe g
WHERE
    t.id = f.fragentyp_id AND
    g.id = f.fragengruppen_id AND
    t.id = 1
ORDER BY f.sortierung ASC
```

Now I need this in Doctrine2 DQL or QueryBuilder. I already learned that D2 is forcing me to think in objects, but I couldn't find any advice how to tag my entities to make this work.

So I'd like to either have the above MySQL query working in my Symfony2 app or some help how to annotate my entities right so I have a working right join connection between BogenAntworten and BogenFragen (the 3 and the 1 are parameters, just so you know). I already set the OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations for all my entities, but I need something to make a right/left join working.

If you want to help me with my entity design:

I have persons (table Person) who answers (table BogenAntworten) questions (table BogenFragen), and when I show the list of questions I either get the last answer from that question (need UPDATE when saving) or there is none and I have to create it (INSERT when saving). Questions also are in one of many types (table BogenTyp) and are in one of many groups (table BogenFragenGruppe)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, found it out myself again. The QueryBuilder of Doctrine2 supports a leftJoin (which is identical to the RIGHT JOIN if you switch the two tables). For those need some code, here is the above SQL statement build with QueryBuilder:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(array('f.id', 'f.frage', 'f.sortierung', 'a.antwort', 'g.name'))
    ->from('MySuperBundle:BogenFragen', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('f.bogenantworten', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.personen = :pid')
    ->from('MySuperBundle:BogenTyp', 't')
    ->from('MySuperBundle:BogenFragenGruppe', 'g')
    ->where('t.id = :tid')
    ->andWhere('t.id = f.bogentypen')
    ->andWhere('g.id = f.bogenfragengruppe')
    ->orderBy('f.sortierung', 'ASC')
    ->setParameter('tid', 1)
    ->setParameter('pid', 3)
    ->getQuery();
```

(The parameters are actually dynamic, but for easier reading I used the numbers of the original SQL statement)